# How to right-align widgets in panel in Kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: kubuntu, panel, plasma, widgets

First, please take a look at this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The problem is...

1. It all happened before I realized what I did. So, I don't know how I messed it up. :(
2. Do you see the panel at the bottom? The 'Time', 'System Tray', and 'Show the Desktop' widgets which are supposed to be aligned right in the panel, are aligned left. Selecting "Panel Tool Box > More Settings >  Panel Alignment > Right" changes nothing.
3. Also, the application switcher in the panel (that allows me to switch between various open apps in a workspace - - like in Windows) is missing.

There should probably be a way to reset it all. I would like to know that, and... I would also like to know how I can manually rearrange things back to default, so that I know how it actually works.

Answer (score 3):

**KDE Plasma desktop**

The KDE panel and the widgets are plasmoids or plasma widgets. More of the KDE plasma: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma .

How to manage the KDE plasma panel: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Panels .

**Probably**

Probably you have removed the "Task Manager". More : http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tasks

[image]

You could add it back (KDE userbase):

> To place a widget in the panel first open the Panel Toolbox and from
>   there open the Widget Explorer (click Add Widgets), locate the widget
>   you wish to add and drag it to the desired position in the Panel.

You could move plasmoids: Open the Panel Toolbox and move mouse cursor over the widget. The cursor should change to the "compas rose". Move the widget to the right place.

Same from the KDE userbase:

> The panel can then be configured by clicking on the toolbox located on
>   the right for horizontal or bottom for vertical panel. At that point,
>   the panel will be in configuration mode. Panel configuration may also
>   be accessed via the context (right click) menu in the panel.
>
> Widgets in the panel can be sorted by dragging them when in
>   configuration mode.

New default panel (KDE userbase):

> To add a new panel either click on the desktop toolbox button and
>   select Add Panel or open the context (right click) menu on the desktop
>   and select Add Panel from the menu.
>
> If more than one kind of Panel is installed, you will be able to
>   select between them to choose what sort of Panel you would prefer. By
>   default, two Panel types are available: Default Panel, which creates a
>   Panel containing all of the default widgets (launcher, pager, tasks,
>   system tray, clock, etc.), and Blank Panel, which adds an empty Panel
>   without any pre-configured widgets in it.

[image]